# haml assign value to input field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, input, haml

I'm trying to insert a value inside an input field, when the field of controller is not empty.

```
%input{:name => "user[email]", :placeholder => "Email", :type => "email", :value => @params[:user][:email] if @params[:user] && @params[:user][:email]}/
```

That is what I'm trying to do, but obviously I'm getting an error:

```
syntax error, unexpected modifier_if, expecting ')'
e => @params[:user][:email] if @params[:user] && @params[:us
                 ^
/xxx/xxx/xxx syntax error, 
unexpected ')', expecting keyword_end
@params[:user][:email])).to_s);; _hamlout.buffer << (">\n<in
                  ^
```

What should I modify to get that working ?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to enclose the conditional value in parenthesis `(...)`

Try this

```
%input{:name => "user[email]", :placeholder => "Email", :type => "email", 
       :value => (@params[:user][:email] if @params[:user] && @params[:user][:email])}
```